# Exclude values that don't match two or more conditions in excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup, multiple-conditions, index-match

I have a table like this:

| Number | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 10.12.2021 |
| 2 | Mark | 10.14.2021 |
| 3 | Joe | 11.16.2021 |
| 4 | Mark | 12.15.2021 |
| 5 | Anna | 11.12.2021 |
| 6 | Joe | 12.20.2021 |

I want to exclude all the rows from the table, that don't match criteria (in this particular case 2 criteria) form second table (name and date before the start date in the table 1):

| Number | Name | Start Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 10.22.2021 |
| 2 | Mark | 11.30.2021 |

In result I should have the table 3 with names excluded rows 1 and 2 (as Joe and Mark started after the date in table 1, so Name matches, but date does not) and exclude row 5 (as Anna does not presence in table 2, so Name does not matches) and with N/A values (or any other value that differs from names) in rows that do not match conditions:

| Number | Name | Date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joe | 10.12.2021 | N/A |
| 2 | Mark | 10.14.2021 | N/A |
| 3 | Joe | 11.16.2021 | Joe |
| 4 | Mark | 12.15.2021 | Mark |
| 5 | Anna | 11.12.2021 | N/A |
| 6 | Joe | 12.20.2021 | Joe |

I've thought it is possible to do with INDEX MATCH:

```
{=INDEX(range1,MATCH(1,(A1=range2)*(B1=range3),0))}
```

However, for some reason it is not work properly if I put B1>=range2 (to chose dates after the start date).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't filter on the desired values?

Comment: Which Excel version do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the inclusion conditions are:

- The name exists in the look up table (table 2)
- `Date >= Start Date`

in `I2` cell use the following formula:

```
=LET(matchNames,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B7,F3:F4)),
 matchDates,MAP(B2:B7,C2:C7, 
 LAMBDA(a,b,IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(a,F3:G4,2,FALSE),b+1)<=b,TRUE, FALSE))),
 FILTER(B2:C7,matchNames*matchDates)
)
```

**Note**: You can find a simplified version of this formula at the end.

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

We use `LET` function to determine the conditions first, so we have  a simplified `FILTER` function.

Remember the `include` input argument of `FILTER(array,include)` is a **Boolean** array *whose height or width is the same as the `array`*.

#### Name Match

```
matchNames,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(B2:B7,F3:F4))
```

`XMATCH` returns the index position of the second input argument in case of match, otherwise `#N/A`, but we need a Boolean value, so we use `ISNUMBER` to convert the result to `TRUE/FALSE`.

The intermediate result would be:

```
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE -> Anna was not found
TRUE
```

#### Date Match

```
matchDates,MAP(B2:B7,C2:C7, 
  LAMBDA(a,b, 
  IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(a,F3:G4,2,FALSE),b+1)<=b,TRUE,FALSE)))
```

We build a new array of the same size as the first two input arguments via `MAP` function. We invoke a `LAMBDA` function to compare the `Date` with `Start Date` for each row of the first two input arguments. So `a` is the name and `b` is the corresponding date.

We use `VLOOKUP` to find the corresponding start date for a given name (`a`) in the lookup array (`F3:G4`). If start date is lower or equal than the date (`b`), we return `TRUE` otherwise `FALSE`.

We need to deal with the situation when the name (`a`) is not found. If that happens `VLOOKUP` returns `#N/A`, but we need a boolean value, so if that is the case we use a condition that is **always** `FALSE`, i.e. `b+1<=b`. Remember in Excel dates are represented as a positive number, so `b+1` is the next day. This situation is going to happen when the name is `Anna` for example.

The output of `MAP` will be:

```
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE -> Anna was not found
TRUE
```

Check the [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) specification for more information on how this function works.

#### Filter

Now we have all the elements to build our `FILTER`:

```
FILTER(B2:C7,matchNames*matchDates)
```

Multiplying both Boolean arrays ensure both conditions are satisfied.

As you may noticed already the boolean array `matchDates` via `VLOOKUP` also checks if the name exists in the lookup table, therefore we don't need `matchNames` condition so the initial formula can be simplified as follow:

```
=LET(matchDates,MAP(B2:B7,C2:C7,LAMBDA(a,b, 
 IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(a,F3:G4,2,FALSE),b+1)<=b,TRUE,FALSE))),
 FILTER(B2:C7,matchDates)
)
```

or removing the `LET` function, since it is not really necessary at this point:

```
=FILTER(B2:C7,MAP(B2:B7,C2:C7, 
 LAMBDA(a,b,IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(a,F3:G4,2,FALSE),b+1)<=b,TRUE,FALSE))))
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify the formula so the result will look like Table 1, but it will be "N/A" values in rows that do not match conditions?

Comment: @VladyslavFedorchenko this should be another question, since it was not specified that way in your question. Anyway this is a way to do it: `=LET(names, B2:B7, dates, C2:C7, matchDates,MAP(names,dates,LAMBDA(a,b,  IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(a,F3:G4,2,FALSE),b+1)<=b,TRUE,FALSE))),  namesUpdated, MAP(names, matchDates, LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b=TRUE, a,NA()))),  datesUpdated, MAP(dates, matchDates, LAMBDA(a,b, IF(b=TRUE, a,NA()))),  HSTACK(namesUpdated, datesUpdated))`. Maybe there are other ways to do it with traditional excel functions, but this works using as input previous `MAP` result from my answer

Comment: @VladyslavFedorchenko anyway for such kind of transformations you can try Power Query